# Creating markers perpendicular to different lines in QGIS

Tags: qgis, markers

I want to create markers on different lines and this markers should have always 90° on the line.

[image]

I used the simple marker, with a 90° angle, but this doesn't work for every line.

How can I get a 90°angle for every line segment?

Comment: Voting to close this question as most requirements are hidden in comments to the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found this question and have another solution for everyone, who come across this.

First create a symbology **at the points** with the type "simple marker". There choose the line symbol as Erik does in his answer. The size parameter controls the length of the line. It will look something like this:

[image]

In a second step use the tool "align points to features" (https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/de/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/cartography.html#qgisangletonearest). The Input layer is your point layer and the reference layer is your line layer. The result looks something like this:

[image]

I hope, this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the layers `style`-tab, add another line-style by clicking the green plus and change this line from `simple line` to `marker line`(now small red circles should show up in the preview window). Then choose the correct marker (see image) and space it accordingly to your needs.

[image]

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have two layers. The first layer contains the lines and the second layer contains points, which are on this line. I want to change this points into line markers. Every marker should have a exact angle of 90° on the first line layer.

Comment: So your markes represent something. Distance, exits, phone booths?

Comment: Yes, the line layer contains roads and the point layer contains points of interest, and they should be line markers with a 90°angle on the line layer

Comment: Possible solution: use the tool `split lines at points` from the Saga-algorithms.  Then use the process above in order to create one marker at beginning of each line segment. To my knowledge the alignment of features across layers is not possible.

Comment: One last addition, the line layer is a WMS and the point layer is stored in a PostgreSQL DB

Comment: I feel kind of trolled right now.

Comment: No I´m sorry for the insufficient description of my problem.

Comment: WMS layers are raster data, meaning there is no geometry whatsoever you could align your points/lines with. Simply use a dot or a star, or get the WMS-data as a shapefile.